# Как отправить сообщение от имени группы вконтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте. Нужно написать бота в сообщениях публичной страницы. В настройках этой самой страницы разрешил сообщения. Создал community token с правами на сообщения, сделал callback api оповещение на новые сообщения в группу.

Оповещения приходят, в ответ на них мне нужно отправить сообщение:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?message=Hello&user_id=USER&access_token=TOKEN&v=5.62
```

TOKEN — community токен, о котором писал выше

USER — пользователь, который только что сам написал в сообщения страницы и я получил его через callback api

Как результат:

> "error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this
>   method"

Если взять обычный standalone-токен, то с его помощью я легко могу отправлять сообщения, но от имени пользователя, который получил токен (меня, например), а нужно от имени группы.
Такое чувство, что эти community messages, полученные из веб-интерфейса, тупо не работают.

Comment: Если кто будет искать, то это баг вконтакте. На группах (не публичных страницах) будет работать пока.